# how to use Dollar sign in password for shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I am connecting to DB2 database from Linux machine via shell script

password = ppp#$user

How can I use this password while connecting to database as the dollar sign is creating a problem here?

Comment: Can you share the full command line you're using?

Answer (score 7):

use single quotes.

```
password='ppp#$user'
```

Comment: The other option is to *escape* the dollar sign, e.g. `\$`. (though I would just single-quote it)